# image search on regular websites

Tags: configuration

If I need to do a regular image search on a site such as bing.com, for some reason tor will only bring back 4 or 5 images no matter what i search for.  Occasionally I might get 7 images, but all of the rest of the 'images' just show up as colored boxes.

When I do an image search on yahoo.com it returns dozens of grey boxes, but no images at all.

I've looked all through about.config trying to figure out what setting would control that, but haven't been able to figure it out.  I checked out all of the images settings, and the timeout settings, but no luck.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You slid the security slider all the way up.

It looks like additional images are loaded with JavaScript, thus you need JavaScript enabled in order to view additional results. Security slider on its highest setting disables JavaScript. Move it to medium or low.

Or temporarily allow scripts on the page with the NoScript button and reload the page.

PS: do not change about:config options unless you want to break Tor Browser and are capable of fixing it yourself.